# Report performance tuning

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx, business-intelligence

I am trying to tune the performance of a report which is taking more than an hour to execute.About 20 minutes for data retrieval and more than 45 minutes for processing.
The dataset workgauge has 4 fields complete, baseline, date, state (using MDX query).
Based on state (there are 6 types of states) few calculations are performed to get different values of complete and baseline. 
These calculations are given as expressions in series properties of line chart. 
There are four lines in this report, each containing expressions. 
I tried to create different datasets  with calculations in the query for each line. 
But on doing this I am not able to plot them onto same chart. It is only taking the values from the first dataset dropped to the chart.
I would like to avoid calculations in report as I believe this could be the reason for low performance.

Any suggestions on how to handle this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps OT, but I really try to avoid SSAS for SSRS. SQL is much more flexible and easier to code and test.  The flexibility is especially important for SSRS charts where its best to pre-calculate and structure everything to simplify the chart properties IMO.

Comment: Your going to need to post your query, the expressions, and maybe a picture of what you are trying to do.  There isn't enough info here to provide a good answer.

Comment: @MikeHoney You sound like someone who doesn't work much with MDX.  There's nothing wrong with using SSAS with SSRS, as long as you use it for appropriate situations (probably not thousands of detail rows). It's easier because you know SQL better.

Comment: one line:
=IIF(Fields!Date.Value<Today
 , SUM(Fields!Baseline.Value)
  + SUM(iif((Fields!State.Value<>"Complete" AND Fields!State.Value<>"Deleted") 
    OR IsNothing(Fields!Baseline.Value)
    , cdec(0.0)
    ,  Cdec(Fields!Completed.Value-Fields!Baseline.Value)
    )
   )
 , Nothing
)


second line:
=IIF(Fields!Date.Value<Today
 , SUM(Fields!Baseline.Value)
  + SUM(iif((Fields!State.Value<>"Complete" AND Fields!State.Value<>"Deferred") 
    OR IsNothing(Fields!Baseline.Value)
    , cdec(0.0)
    ,  Cdec(Fields!Completed.Value-Fields!Baseline.Value)
    )
   )
 , Nothing
)

Comment: @mmarie above mentioned are expression for 2 lines. There are 2 more similar expressions for other 2 lines. I am not able to post the picture of the report.